# Why do I get a NullPointerException when I start my GUI?

Tags: java, swing, exception, user-interface, nullpointerexception

I have coded a gui for my CRUD Program, and when I want to run it I get:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.guimain$1.run(guimain.java:477)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:597)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Thats the code where the NPE comes from:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
                maingui.showStart();// thats the line with the Exception
        }
    });
}
```

and thats the method showStart():

```
public void showStart(){
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().removeAll();
    tabstructure.removeAll();
    Produkt filter=new Produkt();

    JPanel P=new JPanel();
    P=Produktgui(0, filter);
    JPanel R=new JPanel();
    R=Billgui(0);
    JPanel nR=new JPanel();
    nR=Billgui(0);

    tabstructure.addTab("e", P);
    tabstructure.addTab("Bills", R);
    tabstructure.addTab("Pay bill", nR);
    mainFrame.getContentPane().add(tabstructure);
    mainFrame.validate();
    mainFrame.repaint();
    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Why do I get a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: It seems like `maingui` is `null`. Do you initialize it somewhere?

Comment: Not answering your question, but you have a pattern of `JPanel P=new JPanel(); P=Produktgui(0, filter);`. Is there some reason you want to call the JPanel() constructor in these cases? It appears to be unnecessary / without value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because something that you're calling a method on is `null`.

Look carefully at the error message. It says that the exception happens on line 477 of `guimain.java`.

At that point, `maingui` is `null`.

Answer (score 6):

You will have to create an instance of your `MainGui`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final MainGui maingui = new MainGui();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
                maingui.showStart();// thats the line with the Exception
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You must instantiate objects before you can invoke methods on them.  In this case, `maingui` hasn't been instantiated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            MainGUI maingui = new MainGUI();
            maingui.showStart();
        }
    });
}
```